# OpenNLP parser training API for v1.7.x

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I tried training a parser on some corpus as stated in the [manual](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.7.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.parser.training) by Apache OpenNLP, but am stuck at creation of HeadRules object.

```
static HeadRules createHeadRules(TrainerToolParams params) throws IOException {
    ArtifactSerializer headRulesSerializer = null;
          /*
           * Some code here
           */
    Object headRulesObject = headRulesSerializer.create(new FileInputStream(params.getHeadRules()));
    return (HeadRules) headRulesObject;

}
```

I cannot find `TrainerToolParams` class in OpenNLPTools API.

Can someone guide me in details how do we create a HeadRules object to train a parser.
Am very new with openNLP, so please guide me in details.